# App not authorized to use firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have an android app written in kotlin in which I already had firebase authentication implemented. I had to change the firebase account with which the app was previously associated. So, I deleted the project from that account and created a new one. Created a new project there, added my app by adding the package name and SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys in the firebase console. Then, I downloaded the google-services.json file and pasted it in the app module. But, when I try to send the OTP from my app it is giving me this error:

`This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]`

I have checked the package name and SHA keys multiple times and they are correct. I took the SHA keys from android studio by running the `signingReport` gradle task. On previous it was working fine (which I cannot try again as I deleted the project). I also enabled the phone authentication in Sign-In methods in firebase console. Enabled the Play Integrety API.

Is there anything that I might be missing ?

Note: My app is not on play store. I am running it directly from android studio.

I double checked the package name and SHA keys multiple times. They are correct. I have event created different projects and tried it there it also doesn't work on different. I initially thought something might be wrong with my app so I created a brand new app in android studio and just implemented the firebase auth in it and it also didn't worked there. Same error. Verified package name and SHA keys multiple times.